# Python Pandas Dataframe Melt

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this as a dataframe:

```
custid   day  freq
346782   1     0
346782   0     1
346782   1     2
346783   0     0
346783   0     1
346783   0     2
```

But for machine learning purposes I want to semi-transpose this into:

```
346782 1 0 0 1 1 2 
346783 0 0 0 1 0 2
```

You know, so that the custID only comes once with ALL its associated features in one row ahead of it.

I've tried various things such as:

```
df1 = pd.melt(newdf, id_vars=['0']).drop('variable', axis=1).sort_values(0)
```

How can I accomplish this transformation?

Comment: Please use code block next time. `control+k` would work or just 4 space indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `stack` here, you can also try `melt`

```
s=df.set_index('custid').stack()

s.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.index.get_level_values(level=0),s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()])
s.unstack()
Out[843]: 
        0  1  2  3  4  5
custid                  
346782  1  0  0  1  1  2
346783  0  0  0  1  0  2
```

Comment: Perfect! How do you guys know all this stuff?!

Comment: @Ray92 most of time , I learn it during my work , also, if you have time , you can re walk in the pandas api

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel).

```
df.groupby("custid").apply(lambda x: x[["day", "freq"]].values.ravel())
custid
346782    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
346783    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]
dtype: object

pd.DataFrame(
  df.groupby("custid").apply(lambda x: x[["day", "freq"]].values.ravel()).to_dict()
).T

        0   1   2   3   4   5
346782  1   0   0   1   1   2
346783  0   0   0   1   0   2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
In [192]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
            {k: x[['day', 'freq']].values.flatten() for k, x in df.groupby('custid')}, 
            orient='index')
Out[192]:
        0  1  2  3  4  5
346782  1  0  0  1  1  2
346783  0  0  0  1  0  2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!